# ios get label from tag number

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to get a label's attributes from self so I tried:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:1];
```

But all I got was an empty UILabel instead of the label I was looking for.  What is correct way to do this.

Comment: How did you set the tag and is label the only view which is the subview (or further down in the tree) of `self` with the tag `1`?

Comment: I set the tag like [label setTag:1]; in another function. The label is not on the top subview but it is on the top view

Comment: You need to enumerate `self subviews` to get the label you want. Your attempt will not work.

Comment: Is this code in a viewController or a view?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Obviously

```
 UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:1];
```

creates a pointer to the instance of my label with tag 1.  This does actually work.  What doesn't work and why I was having problems came from trying to release *label*.  Releasing *label* is the same as release [self viewWithTag:1] which is not what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

In **Objective C** for getting UILabel in UIViewController by tag.

here i take assumption as your `UILabel` is added on `self.view`, otherwise you can pass your view where you added `UILabel` as `[yourview viewWithTag:1];`

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

In `UITableView`

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

cell is a object of `UITableViewCell` as

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

In **Swift 3**

```
let label:UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
```

In `UITableView`

```
let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as UITableViewCell!

let label:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
```

**NOTE:** before using tag (viewWithTag) there should be object (UILabel) with that tag number, otherwise app is crash.

you can set tag for any object via storyboard or via XIB and programatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer in Swift 3, was useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3, when i am in a view controller, i have to call this code to retrieve a view by tag :

```
self.mInstructionView = self.view.viewWithTag(1)
```